# Hide Emitter not working in particles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, visibility

I tried to uncheck the "Show Emitter" checkbox under the Render tab, but the emitter is still visible.

Comment: when you say that it is still visible, do you mean it is still visible when you render an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you made should hide the emitter from the final render but I'm guessing you mean whilst you're working in the viewport.

In the Properties panel, with the emitter selected uncheck both viewport and render (as needed) under Instancing > Faces:

Properties Panel > Object Properties > Instancing > Faces > (show instancer) viewport + render

[image: Blender settings to hide faces of a particle emitter]